# It's possible add new states to widgets in tk?

Tags: tcl, tk-toolkit

It's possible add extra states to defaults states of a widget ?.

For example, working with styles in tk (ttk) some times the options to configurate a widget are very limited. However, using the command ***ttk::style map*** and (if possible) defining extra states, would be easy to configurate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The low level state management engine maps the states to bits of an integer. The full list of supported states is (this is information extracted straight from the C code; this is utterly the ground truth):

> - **active** — Mouse cursor is over widget or element
> - **disabled** — Widget is disabled
> - **focus** — Widget has keyboard focus
> - **pressed** — Pressed or “armed”
> - **selected** — “on”, “true”, “current”, etc.
> - **background** — Top-level window lost focus (Mac, Win “inactive”)
> - **alternate** — Widget-specific alternate display style
> - **invalid** — Bad value
> - **readonly** — Editing/modification disabled
> - **hover** — Mouse cursor is over widget
> - **reserved1** — Reserved for future extension
> - **reserved2** — Reserved for future extension
> - **reserved3** — Reserved for future extension
> - **user3** — User-definable state
> - **user2** — User-definable state
> - **user1** — User-definable state

Looking through that list, I'd guess that particularly **user1**, **user2** and **user3** are open to use for your extra states. Defining more than that requires custom changes to the C code, but you have three right there to be going on with.
I guess at a pinch, **reserved1**…**reserved3** could also be used. I shudder to think of how complex a UI must be to need that many different independent state descriptors, but they're there and I really doubt that Ttk will make much use of them any time soon. (If you're making a lot of use of this sort of thing, do drop a line to the developers of Tk to let them know about it; it helps persuade people to not “optimise” away this stuff and particularly good uses might lead to a state bit becoming officially named.)

Please don't reinvent the meaning of any existing state flag though. Everything is confusing enough without that!